Integrating Usercentrics Cookiebot with Angular 18 and SSR
I'm building a website with Angular 18 and SSR. However due to EU regulations, cookieconsent form must be implemented. I tried to build one on my own, but it seems to be very hard to detect third party cookies, like once from youtube, google analytics, tiktok, facebook and etc. And actually almost all of my cookies except for the auth and the theme cookies are third party cookies.
This is the reason I decided to go with Usercentrics Cookiebot (seems to be the most affordable solution compared to other cookiebot providers). I have followed their documentation and provided the script to index.html, however it seems to not work correctly. For example, when I decline the youtube cookie (I'm using the nocookie iFrame from youtube), the entire player is removed from the DOM, which breaks my website view (I'm not sure if this is the way it should behave, but I've tried to disable this cookie to many popular websites and the player doesn't disappear). Furthermore when I disable the google analytics cookie, the gtag cookie persists. It looks like the cookiebot is not well integrated with Angular.
Is there someone who has already implemented this and can give me some guidelines how to achieve proper cookieconsent integration?

I've come up with the following solution:
First I created a Consent interface


export interface CookieCategories {
  marketing: boolean;
  statistics: boolean;
  preferences: boolean;
}

export interface Consent extends CookieCategories{
  method: string;
  necessary: boolean;
  stamp: string;
  region: string;
  utc?: number;
  ver?: number;
}



Then I extended the global window object with some methods and properties I'm using in my app.


import { Consent } from "./app/models/usercentrics-cookiebot";

interface Cookiebot {
  renew: () => void;
  show: () => void;
  hide: () => void;
  onaccept: (any) => void;
  consent: Consent;
  // You can add other properties or methods of CookieConsent if needed
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    Cookiebot: Cookiebot;
    CookiebotCallback_OnAccept: () => void;
    CookiebotCallback_OnDecline: () => void;
  }
}



And at the end I created a cookie-consent service, which handles the cookie consent both, on the server and in the browser. This way I always know to which cookies the user has consented and I can hide/show iframes and other third party providers accordingly.


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CookiesConsentService {
  private readonly document = inject(DOCUMENT);
  private readonly shellService = inject(ShellService);
  private readonly ssrCookieService = inject(SsrCookieService);

  private readonly consent$$: BehaviorSubject<CookieCategories> = new BehaviorSubject({marketing: false, preferences: false, statistics: false} as CookieCategories);

  get cookiesConsent$(): Observable<CookieCategories> {
    return this.consent$$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(
        (prev, curr) =>
          prev.statistics === curr.statistics &&
          prev.marketing === curr.marketing &&
          prev.preferences === curr.preferences
      )
    );
  }

  get marketingConsent$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.consent$$.pipe(map(obj => obj.marketing), distinctUntilChanged());
  }

  get statisticsConsent$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return  this.consent$$.pipe(map(obj => obj.statistics), distinctUntilChanged());
  }

  get preferencesConsent$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return  this.consent$$.pipe(map(obj => obj.preferences), distinctUntilChanged());
  }

  constructor() {
    let cookieConsent: string;
    let cookieConsentObj: Consent | undefined;
    const thisWindow = this.document?.defaultView; // on server this will be undefinded, in the browser will refer to the window object

    if (this.shellService.isOnServer) {
      // first handle cookies consent on the server
      cookieConsent = this.ssrCookieService.get('CookieConsent'); // get CookieConsent from request cookie

      if (cookieConsent) { // first time user visits the page the cookie consent will be undefined => emit false (the empty `emitEvents`)
        try {
          cookieConsentObj = JSON.parse(cookieConsent
            .replace(/'/g, '"') // Replace single quotes with double quotes
            .replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+):/g, '"$1":')); // Add double quotes around property names
          this.emitEvents(cookieConsentObj);
          return;
        } catch (e) {
          // do nothing (the empty `emitEvents` handles this case as well)
        }
      }

      this.emitEvents();
    } else {
      // handle cookies consent in the browser initially
      cookieConsentObj = thisWindow?.Cookiebot?.consent;
      this.emitEvents(cookieConsentObj);
    }

    afterNextRender(() => {
      // register cookies consent change callbacks
      if (thisWindow) {
        thisWindow.CookiebotCallback_OnAccept = thisWindow.CookiebotCallback_OnDecline = () => {
          cookieConsentObj = thisWindow?.Cookiebot?.consent;
          this.emitEvents(cookieConsentObj);
        };
      }
    })
  }

  private emitEvents(cookieConsentObj?: Consent) {
    this.consent$$.next({
      marketing: cookieConsentObj?.marketing || false,
      statistics: cookieConsentObj?.statistics || false,
      preferences: cookieConsentObj?.preferences || false,
    });
  }
}



Would be glad to hear your feedback.
